# pong in tkinter, collisions problem between paddles and ball

Tags: python, tkinter, pong

I am having a problem with the ball colliding with the paddles I'm trying to use the coordinates of the ball and if it lines up with the coordinates of the paddles the ball will change direction on the X axis. I believe the problem is that paddles aren't being given coordinates as when I run it through the debugger the list for coordinates is blank

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, diameter, xVelocity, yVelocity, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image = canvas.create_oval(x, y, diameter,diameter, fill=color)
        self.xVelocity = xVelocity
        self.yVelocity = yVelocity

    def ball_at_centre(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.image, 365, 360)
        self.canvas.update()

    def move_ball(self):

            coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)
            self.canvas.move(self.image, self.xVelocity, self.yVelocity)
            print(coordinates)
            if (coordinates[2]>=(self.canvas.winfo_width())):
                self.canvas.move(self.image, -365, -300)
                self.canvas.update()
                self.canvas.move(self.image, self.xVelocity, self.yVelocity)

            if (coordinates[3]>=(self.canvas.winfo_height())):
                self.yVelocity = -3
            if coordinates[0] < 0:
                self.canvas.move(self.image, 365, 300)
                self.canvas.update()
                self.canvas.move(self.image, self.xVelocity, self.yVelocity)

            if coordinates[1] < 0:
                self.yVelocity = 3

    def move_collisions_left(self, image_paddle_one):
        coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)
        coordinates1 = self.canvas.coords(image_paddle_one)
        if coordinates[0] <= 5 and coordinates1[1] < coordinates[1] < coordinates1[3]:
            self.xVelocity = 3

    def move_collisions_right(self, image_paddle_two):
        coordinates2 = self.canvas.coords(image_paddle_two)
        coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)
        if coordinates[2] <= 750 and coordinates2[1] < coordinates[3] < coordinates2[3]:
            self.xVelocity = -3

class PaddleOne:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, x2, y1, y2, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image_paddle_one = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, x2, y1, y2, fill=color)

    def move_paddle(self, direction):
        if direction == "w":
            self.canvas.move(self.image_paddle_one, 0, -20)
        if direction == "s":
            self.canvas.move(self.image_paddle_one, 0, 20)
        print(self.canvas.coords(self.image_paddle_one))
```

The code for the objects

```
from tkinter import *
from objects import *
import time


def play_game():
    global paddle_left
    global paddle_right
    global canvas

    new_window = Tk()
    window.destroy()
    canvas = Canvas(new_window, height=800, width=800,bg='black')
    canvas.pack()
    centre_ball = Ball(canvas, 10, 10, 50, 2, 3, 'white')
    paddle_left = PaddleOne(canvas, 5, 5, 50, 100, 'white')
    paddle_right = PaddleTwo(canvas, 795, 795, 750, 700, 'white')
    new_window.geometry("800x800")
    centre_ball.ball_at_centre()
    while True:
        centre_ball.move_ball()
        new_window.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)

        new_window.bind("<w>", lambda event: paddle_left.move_paddle("w"))
        new_window.bind("<s>", lambda event: paddle_left.move_paddle("s"))
        new_window.bind("<Up>", lambda event: paddle_right.move_paddle("up"))
        new_window.bind("<Down>", lambda event: paddle_right.move_paddle("down"))

        centre_ball.move_collisions_left(paddle_left)
        centre_ball.move_collisions_right(paddle_right)


    new_window.mainloop()
    canvas.update()



    new_window.geometry("800x800")


    new_window.mainloop()

def controls():
    canvas = Canvas(window, height=window.winfo_height(), width=window.winfo_width(), bg='black')
    canvas.pack()
    controls_label = Label(canvas, text="left is wd right is arrowkeys", relief='flat', bg='black', fg='white', font="Times 22 bold")
    controls_label.pack()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")
window.configure(bg='black')

play = Button(window, text="play", font="Times 22 bold", fg='white', activeforeground='white', bg='black', relief='flat', height = 5, width=25, command=play_game)
play.place(x=190, y=200)


controls = Button(window, text="controls", font="Times 22 bold", fg='white', activeforeground='white', bg='black', relief='flat', height = 5, width=25, command=controls)
controls.place(x=190, y=400)


window.mainloop()
```

the main code

Comment: You pass incorrect arguments `paddle_left` and `paddle_right` (instances of `PaddleOne` and `PaddleTwo`) to `centre_ball.move_collisions_left()` and `centre_ball.move_collisions_right()` correspondingly.  They should be `paddle_left.image_paddle_one` and `paddle_right.image_paddle_two` (item IDs) instead.

Comment: Also it is not recommended to use while/for loop inside the main thread of tkinter application.

Comment: thank you this fixed the code it is running properly now